# matlab parfor loop is slower than a normal for loop

Tags: matlab

So I am looking to speed up some processes we run in Matlab.

I came across this [matlab page](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/parfor.html). So I decided to run their example,

**Normal for loop**

```
tic
n = 200;
A = 500;
a = zeros(1,n);
for i = 1:n
    a(i) = max(abs(eig(rand(A))));
end
toc
```

**using parfor**

```
tic
n = 200;
A = 500;
a = zeros(1,n);
parfor i = 1:n
    a(i) = max(abs(eig(rand(A))));
end
toc
```

The normal for loop took 42 seconds. I ran the parfor twice as mentioned in the notes on the matlab page. The first run was 48 seconds &  the second run was 49 seconds.

Why are they slower? On the matlab page is said with the parfor loop it will take approx 10 seconds.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Do you have Parallel Computing Toolbox installed? If not, the `parfor` loop runs locally with no parallelism.

Comment: @Edric ah! that will be it then. I assumed (incorrectly) if I didn't have the toolbox installed it would throw an error when trying to use it. Cheers